# Scraping e-commerce in python - cannot fetch product categories and total amounts

Tags: python, web-scraping

So far my code can scrape the number of items on sale in the category Charms. But I cannot make it print out the name of the category.

The site uses an infinite scroller - but I managed to identify where the sites are and thus the site URL contains {} which is filled out with the **while** loop.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = "https://us.pandora.net/en/charms/?sz=30&start={}&format=page-element"


def fetch_items(link,page):
    Total_items = 0 
    while page<=1000:
        #print("current page no: ",page)
        res = requests.get(link.format(page),headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        list_total = soup.select('.grid-tile .price-standard')  
        Total_items += len(list_total)
        #print(Total_items)
        page+=30
    category_tags = soup.select('span.breadcrumb-element')
    return Total_items
    return category_tags

if __name__ == '__main__':
    page = 0
    product_list = []
    total_items = fetch_items(url,page)

#print number of items on sale
print(total_items)
print(category_tags)
```

**Here's what I need:**
I need to print out the category of the scraped items, which can be found in using this line:

```
category_tags = soup.select('span.breadcrumb-element')
```

But I cannot make it print somehow.

While we're at it, how can I make the code print out ALL the items and not just the items on sale?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
So building one of the guys' code I ended up with this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url1 = "https://us.pandora.net/en/charms/?sz=30&start={}&format=page-element"
url2 = "https://us.pandora.net/en/bracelets/?sz=30&start={}&format=page-element"
url3 = "https://us.pandora.net/en/rings/?sz=30&start={}&format=page-element"
url4 = "https://us.pandora.net/en/necklaces/?sz=30&start={}&format=page-element"
url5 = "https://us.pandora.net/en/earrings/?sz=30&start={}&format=page-element"

#res = requests.get(link.format(url1),headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url1.format(0)).text, 'lxml')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url2.format(0)).text, 'lxml')
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url3.format(0)).text, 'lxml')
soup4 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url4.format(0)).text, 'lxml')
soup5 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url5.format(0)).text, 'lxml')

total_items1 = ''.join(re.findall(r'\d', soup1.select_one('span.products-count').text))
total_items2 = ''.join(re.findall(r'\d', soup2.select_one('span.products-count').text))
total_items3 = ''.join(re.findall(r'\d', soup3.select_one('span.products-count').text))
total_items4 = ''.join(re.findall(r'\d', soup4.select_one('span.products-count').text))
total_items5 = ''.join(re.findall(r'\d', soup5.select_one('span.products-count').text))

#categories = [tag['title'].strip() for tag in soup.select('.refinement-link[title]')

#total_items_sale1 = ''.join(re.findall(r'\d', soup1.select_one('.grid-tile .price-standard')))
#total_items_sale1
#total_items_sale1
#total_items_sale1
#total_items_sale1

#print('Categories:')

#for category in categories:
    #print('\t{}'.format(category))
print('\nTotal Charms: {}'.format(total_items1))
print('\nTotal Bracelets: {}'.format(total_items2))
print('\nTotal Rings: {}'.format(total_items3))
print('\nTotal Necklaces: {}'.format(total_items4))
print('\nTotal Earrings: {}'.format(total_items5))
```

I know it looks horrible. How can we shorten it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the result from the server, you don't have to loop through all pages. All the info you have on one page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://us.pandora.net/en/charms/?sz=30&start={}&format=page-element"
sale_url = "https://us.pandora.net/en/sale/sale-charms/?sz=30&start={}&format=page-element"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(0)).text, 'lxml')
sale_soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(sale_url.format(0)).text, 'lxml')

total_items = soup.select_one('#products_count')['value']
total_sale_items = sale_soup.select_one('#products_count')['value']

categories = [tag['title'].strip() for tag in soup.select('.refinement-link[title]')]

print('Categories:')
for category in categories:
    print('\t{}'.format(category))

print('\nTotal items: {}'.format(total_items))
print('Total sale items: {}'.format(total_sale_items))
```

Prints:

```
Categories:
    Charms
    New Arrivals
    Best Sellers
    Clips
    Spacers
    Dangles
    Safety Chains
    Alphabet & Symbols
    Animals & Pets
    Birthday
    Touch of Color
    Disney
    Family
    Holidays
    Christmas
    Inspirational
    Symbols of Love
    Nature
    Passions
    Vacation & Travel
    Wedding & Anniversary
    Last Chance
    Pandora Reflexions™
    $0 - $50
    $50 - $100
    $100 - $150
    $150 & Over
    Charms
    New Arrivals
    Best Sellers
    Clips
    Spacers
    Dangles
    Safety Chains
    Alphabet & Symbols
    Animals & Pets
    Birthday
    Touch of Color
    Disney
    Family
    Holidays
    Christmas
    Inspirational
    Symbols of Love
    Nature
    Passions
    Vacation & Travel
    Wedding & Anniversary
    Last Chance
    Pandora Reflexions™

Total items: 959
Total sale items: 376
```

Comment: I would really like it, if you could point out where I could input this line ```res = requests.get(link.format(page),headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})``` to add the user agent

Comment: @doomdaam you could write `soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(0), headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}).text, 'lxml')` in the code

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Do you think it's possible to implement beside the "Total items : 961"the number of products which are on sale, right beside it? that would be great.

Comment: You can fetch the total item without using regex like this `total_items = soup.select_one('#products_count')['value']`.

Comment: @doomdaam Updated my answer. For sale items you need different URL.

Comment: @AndrejKesely this is great! Thanks a lot. Now I just need to shorten my own code, as I need to include all the categories. I edited my original question, if it helps.

Comment: @doomdaam Make another question please. Updating question every time is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

can't have 2 returns there. The function stops after that first return, so if you want to return multiple objects, you can put that in one line. You also need to append that within a list within the loop. You have that outside of your loop. Note, I change it from 1000 to 300 to just test it.

Secondly, I think what you want is the text.

To print all the items, you'll need to get each item, not just the ones with `'price-standard'`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = "https://us.pandora.net/en/charms/?sz=30&start={}&format=page-element"


def fetch_items(link,page):
    Total_items = 0 
    categories = []
    while page<=300:
        #print("current page no: ",page)
        res = requests.get(link.format(page),headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        list_total = soup.select('.grid-tile .price-standard')  
        Total_items += len(list_total)
        #print(Total_items)
        page+=30
        print(page)
        category_tags = soup.select('span.breadcrumb-element')[0]
        try:
            categories.append(category_tags.text)
        except:
            categories.append('N/A')
    return Total_items, categories



page = 0
total_items = fetch_items(url,page)

#print number of items on sale
print(total_items[0])
print(total_items[1])
```

Here's how you can go about getting the whole products:

```
def fetch_items(link,page):
    Total_items = 0 
    names = []
    categories = []
    prices = []
    sales = []
    while page<=300:
        res = requests.get(link.format(page),headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

        products = soup.find_all("li", class_=lambda value: value and value.startswith("grid-tile"))
        for each in products:
            Total_items += 1
            category = each.find('div', {'class':'product-tile'})['data-cgid']
            name = each.find('div', {'class':'product-name'}).text.strip()
            price = each.find('div', {'class':'product-pricing'}).text.strip()
            sale_price = each.find('span', {'class':'price-sales'}).text.strip()

            names.append(name)
            categories.append(category)
            prices.append(price)
            sales.append(sale_price)
        print(page)
        page+=30

    return Total_items, names, categories, prices, sales


results = fetch_items(url,page)
```

Not Sure how you want those results though. But you can dump that into a table if you'd like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'name':results[1],
         'category':results[2],
         'price':results[3],
         'sale':results[4]})
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.head(10).to_string())
                                                name category   price    sale
0                        American Icons Dangle Charm   charms  $60.00  $60.00
1  Disney Pixar, Toy Story, Buzz Lightyear Dangle...   charms  $70.00  $70.00
2        Disney Pixar, Toy Story, Woody Dangle Charm   charms  $60.00  $60.00
3                        Spinning Globe Dangle Charm   charms  $60.00  $60.00
4                                     Elephant Charm   charms  $45.00  $45.00
5                 Canada Dangle Charm, Pandora Rose™   charms  $65.00  $65.00
6                             Sparkling Monkey Charm   charms  $70.00  $70.00
7                       Propeller Plane Dangle Charm   charms  $55.00  $55.00
8                                Spotted Heart Charm   charms  $50.00  $50.00
9                              Pink Travel Bag Charm   charms  $50.00  $50.00
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my request. I'm not aiming to know the specific products, only the total amount of items in each category, and the total amounts of items on sale for each category. But you're correct, I need to output them into excel eventually

Comment: oh. ok. I see what you mean now. I did misunderstand, but atleast you have an additional example to do some other things with if needed